# MySQL Workbencb while running pops out error message about keychain

Tags: mysql-workbench

When I open my mysql workbench on mac, the message pops up saying----- The specified item could not be found in the keychain. (-25300). How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It's so simple to fix it.

Enter in manage connections, open the connection and then click on "clear" button that is located near to "Store in Keychain...".

Then click on "Store in Keychain" and write your password.

This fix the problem, at least in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to 6.3.10 when I got this problem, and problem went away. Old versions of MySQLWorkbench are available [here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/).

Using the last 8.x version that works with Mojave (which was 8.0.21), I also 1) couldn't connect to a local MySQL 5.7 instance from MacPorts, and 2) couldn't tell the tabs apart with the new tab design. Sigh, designers.

So I had other reasons for downgrading.